# gatsby-plugin-transition-link AniLink not working on build

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My AniLink transitions work fine on my local machine with *gatsby develop* and with *gatsby serve*. 
But with *gatsby build*, and put on my server I only get a page change with no animation.

Clicking on the image in the slider should have a transition paint drip but it only gets a change of page.

Here is a test site http://www.lukedohner.com/bootstrap-ld/react-site/public/

Do I need to do something to bring in this for the gatsby build?

```
AniLink from "gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink"
```

/slider component

```
<AniLink className={`swipermy-slide-link-ani`}  paintDrip to="/redemption" duration={1} hex="#ffffff"></AniLink>
```

/gatsby-config.js

```
    plugins: [

        `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
          options: {
            name: `images`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
          },
        },
        `gatsby-plugin-transition-link`,

        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
          options: {
            name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
            short_name: `starter`,
            start_url: `/`,
            background_color: `#663399`,
            theme_color: `#663399`,
            display: `minimal-ui`,
            icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
          },
        },


        // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
        // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.app/offline
        // 'gatsby-plugin-offline',
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to this with it only working on some pages. The issue was with the specific page json 404ing.

check your console and if there are any errors on a page it may be blocking the js that handles transitions from being run